# Flutter BottomNavigationBar Animation not functioning

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, pageviews, bottom-navigation-bar

My code works fine where I use `PageView` to navigate between 3 screens. These 3 screens can be swiped right (and back) and also there is a `BottomNavigationBar`, which also works just fine, and it is connected to the items in the `PageView`. But it seems like the animation in the `BottomNavigationBar` is not working, even though the screen/page does get updated. Any idea why? No error is shown.

```
   class MyHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<MyHomeScreen> createState() => _MyHomeScreenState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomeScreenState extends State<MyHomeScreen> {
      bool value = true;
      int currentIndex = 0;
    
      PageController _pageController = PageController(
        initialPage: 0,
      );
    
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Container(),
              Container(
                child: Expanded(
                  child: PageView(
                    controller: _pageController,
                    onPageChanged: (page) {
                      setState(() {
                        currentIndex = page;
                      });
                    },
                    children: [
                      SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(),
                            ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {},),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Screen2(),
                      Screen3(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            selectedItemColor: Colors.black54,
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
            showUnselectedLabels: true,
            showSelectedLabels: true,
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(),
            ],
            currentIndex: currentIndex,
            onTap: (value) {
              currentIndex = value;
              _pageController.animateToPage(
                value,
                duration: Duration(microseconds: 200),
                curve: Curves.linear,
              );
              setState((){});
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Code updated but no difference in outcome.

```
 onTap: (value){
              _pageController.animateToPage(
                value,
                duration: Duration(microseconds: 200),
                curve: Curves.linear,
              );
            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using small unit `Duration(microseconds: 200),`, hard to detect. Try like`duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),` to have some visual animation effect.

```dart
onTap: (value) {
  currentIndex = value;
  _pageController.animateToPage(
    value,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), //increase duration based on your need
    curve: Curves.linear,
  );
  setState(() {});
},
),
```

More about [`Duration`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.0/dart-core/Duration-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the onTap callback you just have to animate to the new page because the PageView's onPageChanged callback will setState to the new index.

You dont have to do that inside of your onTap callback as it will immediately navigate to the new page and force the widget to rebuild so animation won't work.

So inside of onTap, just write this:

```
_pageController.animateToPage(
    value,
    duration: Duration(microseconds: 200),
    curve: Curves.linear,
);
```

Comment: I've tried as per your suggestion but no difference in outcome. See code update above.